# AS3 - Get tags from text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to trace out the tags with the hash **(#Example #FOO #hello_world #foo-bar #2012)** at the end of the text but not the ones within the text?

> Lorem ipsum dolor http://www.example.com/#about consetetur #sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed #diamnonumy eirmod tempor #invidunt ut labore #Example #FOO #hello_world #foo-bar #2012

Thanks. Uli

Comment: what about `#sit_amet,#diamnonumy,#invidunt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to sub_stantial's approach, though I always feel, that it's best to operate with arrays:

```
function returnEndHashtags(message:String):Array
{
    var lastHashtagIndex:int;
    var words:Array = message.split(" ");
    var l:int = words.length;

    for (var i = l-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (!(words[i].toString().charAt(0) == "#"))
        {
            lastHashtagIndex = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return words.slice(lastHashtagIndex);
}
```

1. Make a word array from the text.
2. Iterate from the end of the array, finding the last word beginning with a "#".
3. Return an array of words from the last word beginning with "#" to the array end.

Let's hope a wizard shows up and tells how to do it with regular expressions.

Comment: I need to remove the found tags from the text. There is a problem if the last word in the sentence is marked as a tag because it gets removed too. Does anybody sees a solution for fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm should go like this :

1. Start reading from the end of line
2. Read a word (check for space to get a word)
3. Check for a '#' as the first character of that word
4. If yes, push it to your list of hash tags, go to step 2
5. Else, exit

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to find the list of hashtagged words on the end:

```
/(\s?#([\w-])+)+$/g
```

Then use this to find all the tags within it:

```
/#[\w-]+/g
```

As always, refer to the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) for specifics on how to use regex and the ever excellent [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) for quick and dirty testing.